# What do I additional code do I add to my forloop to prevent it from overwriting my output?

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I have my code here:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

cnxn_string = conn_str = pyodbc.connect(
    'Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;'
    'Server=server;'
    'Database=db;'
    'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
    )

select_all_tables_query = pd.read_sql_query("""SELECT table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE'""", cnxn_string)
tables = ['table1', 'table2']
for table in tables:
    sql_query=pd.read_sql_query(f"SELECT * FROM {table}", cnxn_string)
df=pd.DataFrame(sql_query)
df.to_csv(r'C:\path\to\exported\file\location\{table}.csv', index=False)
```

It keeps overwriting the file name with the last table I have in my list. And it only exports 1 csv file? I'm not sure why. When I run it, this is my output:

```
c:\path_to_python_file.py:19: UserWarning: pandas only supports SQLAlchemy connectable (engine/connection) or database string URI or sqlite3 DBAPI2 connection. Other DBAPI2 objects are not tested. Please consider using SQLAlchemy.   sql_query=pd.read_sql_query(f"SELECT * FROM {table}", cnxn_string) 

c:\path_to_python_file.py:19: UserWarning: pandas only supports SQLAlchemy connectable (engine/connection) or database string URI or sqlite3 DBAPI2 connection. Other DBAPI2 objects are not tested. Please consider using SQLAlchemy.   sql_query=pd.read_sql_query(f"SELECT * FROM {table}", cnxn_string)
```

It's not selecting the name of each table after every iteration. I don't know what to add to my forloop so it iterates through each table then writes it, then iterates again.

Comment: You have an indent problem with the last 2 lined. Put them inside the for loop

Comment: i fixed my indentation and it's still overwriting it and outputting one file

Comment: not sure how i would declare the sql_query above the forloop because I am using {table} inside of it so if it's above, it won't be defined

Comment: hm python is telling me the syntac isn't right here:

sql_query=concat([sql_query, pd.read_sql_query(f"SELECT * FROM {table}", cnxn_string)])

Comment: tables = ['table1', 'table2'], this probably need to be replaced by the values in select_all_tables_query (print it to check that you the result is as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like this might work:
(don't have acsess to data etc)

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

cnxn_string = conn_str = pyodbc.connect(
    'Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;'
    'Server=server;'
    'Database=db;'
    'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
    )

select_all_tables_query = pd.read_sql_query("""SELECT table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE'""", cnxn_string)
# This is probably an issue
## tables = ['table1', 'table2']
tables = select_all_tables_query['TABLE_NAME'].values.to_list()
for table in tables:
    sql_query=pd.read_sql_query(f"SELECT * FROM {table}", cnxn_string)

    # use f rather and not r to include a variable wihthin a string
    sql_query.to_csv(f'C:/path/to/exported/file/location/{table}.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: this still overwrote the file in the forloop

Comment: result_df.to_csv line seems to be outside of the for loop, is that really correct

Comment: have edited which will result into one file per table